# Get information about a stack of images, without plotting it

Tags: image

A very long time ago I used *Mathematica* for a few months and found it very intuitive. Now for my work I use MATLAB. I was just trying some stuff out with *Mathematica* again and there is something I cannot quite get the hang of.

I import a stack of images.  Then I want to know the dimensions of my stack, but when I use `Length` or `Dimensions`, it only lists the number of images. Also when I use `?` it not only shows me information, but it also plots every single "image" in it, which takes very long.

My question here is how to get the image size(s) for the imported stack of images?

Comment: An example (test file) illustrative of your set of images would be helpful. Also see `ref/format/DICOM`

Comment: Hmm first I didnt understand what you meant by `ref/format/DICOM` and googling it even took me to MatLab for some reason. But now that I found [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/DICOM.html) its really useful. You want me to show some images here?

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for your help. I added examples to the question. I cant upload actual files as its sensitive data.

Comment: Yes, the link that you found is the one that I was referring to. If you just pasted what I wrote in Mathematica's documentation, it would've given you the same page. Thanks for the example :)

Comment: Your question really *is* broad. Could you possibly narrow it down to fit the title?

Comment: @YvesKlett oh yeah sorry, got carried away when adding examples, Ill narrow it down again

Comment: You should look at the help for  `CompundExpression ( ;)`  to get an idea where and how to use it esp. in contrast with Matlab. Also, `?` is perhaps not what you want. Look up `ImageDimensions` and related.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thats good advice, thank you. ImageDimensions did the trick! That gave me exactly what I wanted ( and what `size()` would have given me in matlab ). The related functions are also helping me with the transformations. So my mistake was not to realise that in _Mathematica_ images are not just arrays. Thank you for answering my question. You dont want to do that formally so I can accept it?

Comment: I will post an answer, and would propose an edit to your question to remove all clutter. Do you have a multi-image DICOM sample image (other than the `ExampleData` one)?

Comment: I found a zip [here](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/DATA/BRAINIX.zip) I can extract an example from that. How can I post a file in my question?

Comment: I edited your question rather drastically to reflect the actual question. Hopefully this is o.k. for you, otherwise you could roll back.

Comment: No thats no prolem. It is exactly the question you answered, and the one that helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ImageDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageDimensions.html) for this purpose (in this case for a multi-frame [`DICOM`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/DICOM.html)):

```
imagestack = 

  Import["http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/MR-MONO2-8-\16x-heart.gz"];

Length[imagestack]

ImageDimensions /@ imagestack

(* 16 *)

(* {{256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 

  256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 

  256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}, {256, 256}} *)

ListAnimate[img]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: While the above is probably the most practical approach (+1), it might be worth noting that the dimensions are available in the `"MetaInformation"`, at least for the example file: `{"FrameCount", "Rows", "Columns"} /. Import["http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/MR-MONO2-8-16x-heart.gz", "MetaInformation"]` --> `{16, 256, 256}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 please do post another answer, that is very useful information.

Answer (score 5):

One can get information about the images in a file from the metadata, provided it is there in the first place.

For example, in Yves Klett's example file, the `"MetaInformation"` contains information about `"FrameCount"`, `"Rows"`, and `"Columns"`.  These can be obtained as follows:

```
{"FrameCount", "Rows", "Columns"} /.
  Import["http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/MR-MONO2-8-16x-heart.gz",
         "MetaInformation"]
(* {16, 256, 256} *)
```

One can get the image dimensions of the frames from the element `"ImageSize"`, too:

```
Import["http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/MR-MONO2-8-16x-heart.gz",
       "ImageSize"]
(* {256, 256} *)
```